# Do I need a transit visa for waiting 23 hours in Dubai airport?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dubai, dxb

I am an Indian citizen living in Ukraine. I will be traveling to India but I need to wait in Dubai airport 23 hours for my next flight to India. I will not be leaving Dubai airport.  So in this case do I need a transit visa?

Comment: Related http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22299/dubai-uae-visa-requirements-when-staying-in-the-airport?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you are flying into and then out of Dubai, from the same airport and airline, and do not intend to leave the transit area, no visa is necessary for a 23 hour layover.

Comment: I have seen in some post that over 8 Hours in dubai airport a visa for transit is required for onward journey?

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on which airport you are landing at. Dubai has three airports, two of which are for passenger use (one is strictly for cargo).

1. If you are landing at Dubai International, and you have boarding passes for your connecting flight - you will not need a transit visa. The entire transit lounge is fully accessible and you can move between terminals freely.
2. If you are landing at Dubai International and you need to switch airlines and collect bags, you will need a transit visa. This is usually the case if you are flying on a LCC (Low Cost Carrier) which do not check your bags through - [although flydubai is an exception](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/connecting_with_flydubai/connecting_with_flydubai.aspx).

This doesn't apply to you, but adding here for completeness:

3. If you are landing at the [DWTC airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubai_World_Central_-_Al_Maktoum_International_Airport) and transiting through Dubai International, you will need a transit visa as these airports are far apart and you need to go through Dubai.

Finally if you do get tired at the airport (23 hours is long time), and you have proof of onward journey (usually a boarding pass and ticket), you can get a transit visa that will allow you a chance to visit Dubai and spend a few hours there. You will need at least 6 months validity on your passport to apply.

If you are flying on Emirates they can arrange this directly for you, if not - simply follow the signs for immigration and at the bank counter ask for a transit visa.