# Do I require a transit visa for Dubai?

Tags: visas, airport-transfer

I am travelling to Durban on 21.10.2017. I will be reaching Dubai at 22:00 at Terminal 1 and my next flight to Durban is at 10:45 the next day from Terminal 3. This means I will have to remain at Dubai Airport for 12 hours 45 minutes in total.

As the layover time is quite long, do I need to have a transit visa if I stay within the airport terminals and does not come out?

Comment: In my opinion, a downvote of this question is unwarranted. The OP gives far more information than we normally get. It is not a bad question, per se, but possibly is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you do not intend to leave the airport, and head outside. You do not require a "transit" visa. You will head straight to the "transfer" section of the airport and stay within that zone - ie duty etc

Comment: If you don't actually _know_ the answer, please don't post guesses.

Comment: I do know the answer, and the answer is correct. Here is another reference to what I am saying. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37949/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-waiting-23-hours-in-dubai-airport

Comment: Dude, the answer I was commenting on said, and I quote the whole answer, "I don't think so, as long as you don't leave the airport." Thank you for updating your answer, but it really is a crappy move to then pretend that my comment was completely unwarranted. Also, when you say "Here is _another_ reference" (my emphasis), that's not "another" reference, but the only reference you've ever mentioned.

Comment: @Haris Please [edit] your answer to include the reference

Comment: As long as the op stays within Concourses 1 and 3 and the connecting area between them, there is no need to go through immigration (and consequently, no visa required.)

Comment: you've got some real issues, I update the answer for more detail and now you come out with a petty comment like that @DavidRicherby sigh

Comment: @Haris As I said, thanks for the update. My issue was with the way you changed your answer and then replied to my comment as if I was making a completely invalid comment about your current answer.